# ActionMailer method call returning nil in module while rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, actionmailer

I have an `ActionMailer` class

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
  default from: "no-reply@spicy-millennium.com" 

  def submission_reminder user 
    @user = user           
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Your timesheet needs to be submitted!" 
  end    
end
```

If I call `UserMailer.submission_reminder(current_user)` in development it returns me a `Mail::Message` object like expected.

The place in my application where this method is called is in a module I have in the lib folder:

```
module TimesheetSubmissionNotifier                            
  def self.send_submission_reminders
    User.all.each { |user| UserMailer.submission_reminder(user).deliver }
  end
end
```

When I call `TimesheetSubmissionNotifier.send_submission_reminders` in development, UserMailer.submission_remind(user) returns the mail message and deliver is called, everything works as it should.

**The problem is when I call `TimesheetSubmissionNotifier.send_submission_reminders` through an rspec test, `UserMailer.submission_reminder(user)` returns nil.**

If I call `UserMailer.submission_reminder(user)` directly from an rspec test, it returns the mailer message like expected.

Here are the only lines related to ActionMailer in my config/environment/test.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Any ideas why the method is returning nil?

Comment: When you say calling `UserMailer.submission_reminder(user)` directly from an rspec test works, how are you initializing the **user** object you pass to the method? You get it from Users table or you build it with a Factory, etc.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those who have a similar problem, I found the issue.

I was using the `should_receive` RSpec expectation, which I didn't realise actually created a mock of the class it is placed on.  So I was mocking out the UserMailer class entirely which meant that it was never reaching the actual UserMailer class.

I couldn't get it working by using the mock functions, so instead I changed my test to look at the `UserMailer.deliveries` store and check that the right amount of messages are put in there and that they are being sent to the right email addresses.

Comment: Yeah I did this as well, there is an easy to google example that does this. It is worth warning people this is a very *wrong* way to test this. Should_receive is mocking a method endpoint, but doesn't define any sort of return value unless you do that explictly (the receive has nothing to do with receiving e-mails ;-)).

Comment: Technically, should_receive doesn't create a mock object, it stubs out the method and returns nil (rspec docs refer to this as a partial mock).  You can call through to the original method with and_call_original.  eg. should_receive(:submission_reminder).and_call_original

Comment: We ran into this upgrading to rails 4.  We were using sidekiq delay which changed during the upgrade to raise a RuntimeError 'returned an undeliverable mail object' if the mailer returns nil.   Mailer.should_receive(:submission_reminder).and_call_original fixed the tests.

Comment: Mailer.should_receive(:submission_reminder).and_call_original is officially old-syntax. Try not to ever `and_call_original` if you can possibly avoid it. Using empty Openstructs is preferred for making your specs faster, and in Unit testing the idea is to mock out everything not touching the object you're testing